# Keydown instead of click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, keydown

Trying to make make page refresh when the enter key pressed, as opposed to the default click on a button. I assume that an event listener is needed by not sure how to call the button.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
function refresh (e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13){

    }
  }
  $('body').on('keydown', refresh);
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='win'>
  <button><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none">Play Again</a></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want the enter key to trigger the button click?

Answer (score 1):

This should work to refresh page when you hit `ENTER` whose keyCode is **13**

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: generally better to use `document` instead of `"body"`. The body can actually be smaller than viewport

Comment: @charlietfl, yeah you are right sir, I have edited the answer :), thanks for commenting.